How to map Firestore document presented in json-specific format (Firestore data model) to java class?
I obtain JSON from PubSub message. JSON represents a document from Firestore (a specific Firestore data model with additional intermediate objects that define the type of field).
I need to map this specific JSON to a Java POJO class.
I can't use Firestore API to retrieve documents directly from Firestore.
My java classes
 class Worker {
    String name;
    List<Instrument> instruments;
    
    //getters , setters, constructor
  }
  
  class Instrument {
    String instrumentName;
    int cost;
    
    //getters , setters, constructor
  }

Specific json (represents Firestore data model)
{
  "name": {
    "stringValue": "Bob"
  },
  "instruments": {
    "arrayValue": {
      "values": [
        {
          "mapValue": {
            "fields": {
              "instrumentName": {
                "stringValue": "hummer"
              },
              "cost": {
                "integerValue": "7"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "mapValue": {
            "fields": {
              "instrumentName": {
                "stringValue": "screwdriver"
              },
              "cost": {
                "integerValue": "5"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]    

    }  
  }
}


Could you please say if there exists some Java library to convert it? I was trying common solutions like Jackson and Gson, however, looks like they work fine with regular JSON representation like this
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "instrumens": [
    {
      "instrumentName": "hummer",
      "cost": "7"
    },
    {
      "instrumentName": "screwdriver",
      "cost": "5"
    }
  ]
} 

but not with the specific structure I described previously.
Also, I don't want to change POJO classes by adding those intermediate objects like "arrayValue" or "stringValue".
On top of that, I checked that Firestore has such a class as DocumentSnapshot, and I think it is possible to create such a snapshot (as I understand it is a representation of that specific JSON - Firestore data model), but, again, looks like it is possible to convert only regular JSON to such DocumentSnapshot.
Thank you for your help.
I tried to use Jackson and Gson. However, looks like it is not so good for this task.

The second JSON structure you show is how the DocumentSnapshot class of the Firebase SDKs represents the data, and it has built-in support for serializing to/from Java classes.
The first JSON structure you show is the gRPC representation of a document.  I don't think there's a Google/Firebase-provided library to convert that to/from Java clases, but that's also a question that's more suited for a search engine (as recommending off-site resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow). This shows some promising results: https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+grpc+to+java+class

You shared two database JSON structures. As @FrankvanPuffelen already mentioned in his comment, the first structure shows the gRPC representation of a Firestore document. As far as I know, there is no official library that can help you convert that to/from a POJO class. But as suggested, you can search for an alternative or create one yourself.
The second one is actually the representation of the data that exists in a document in the form of DocumentSnapshot object. Such an object can be serialized/serialized to/from a Java class using the toObject() method which:

Returns the contents of the document converted to a POJO or null if the document doesn't exist.


Hey Jack. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
